# DSPACE community list move

Tags: dspace

I have an installation of DSPACE 5.6, I had a community list like this:

Thesis
    |________Math (id 31)
    |________Music

Now I don't know how, after the creation of a sub-community(Math1) Under math the community list appears as

Math (id 31)
 |____ math1

Thesis
 |_____Music

So math now is a community. 
I have seen in the log somthing like this

```
`"session_id=F77353A9D371994D36C7B3D3037FD:ip_addr=192.168.144.17:delete_community:community_id=31(Math)"`
```

But after that there isn't somthing that confirm the delete like the phrase

```
"remove_subcommunity:parent_comm_id=.. chid_comm_id=.."
```

So I don't know what happened. And how I can resolve this problem.
It seems as the community math lost his parents id.
Could you help me?
Thanks
Best regards

Comment: I am confused by the formatting of this question.  What is the purpose of the string of underscores "____" in your question?

Comment: Dear terry,   I would like to explain graphically the community list hierarchy with the "___".

Comment: Dear terry,   I would like to explain graphically the community list hierarchy with the "___". In the first case math and music are sub community of Thesis . A staff user said that after addng a sub community to math the math community lost the parent relation with Thesis and became a community. In the log I see that the user have done a delete but there only the line `"session_id=F77353A9D371994D36C7B3D3037FD:ip_addr=192.168.144.17:delete_community:community_id=31(Math)"`. I hope that now is more clear thanks best regards

Comment: If this question is still open, I recommend editing the question text to make the question more clear.  If you are unable to edit the question text, I recommend closing the question and starting a new one.

Comment: Dear Terry, the problem on my dspace is this a subcommunity lost his parlental reletionship so now it is a community. (The subcommunity math was under thesis and now it is a community without reletion with theisis). In the log I found that there was this line session_id=F77353A9D371994D36C7B3D3037FD:ip_addr=192.168.144.17:delete_community:community_id=31(Math). But there wasn't other line that confirm the cancellation of the community math. So I ask according to you what could happend. And how move the subcommunity math under thesis again. Thanks Best regards

Comment: I recommend that you update your question so other folks can offer help on your question.  StackOverflow is not a good place for a threaded conversation.

If this format does not work for you, see https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSPACE/Support